# Visual Studio 2015 Missing Features (Metro Development)

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Anyone else using Visual Studio 2015 to develop Metro applications?  I just upgrade this week - fresh install of VS2015 and Windows 10.  When I try to create a project that targets Windows 8.1 I get a message that says the feature isn't installed.  When I click on the 'Install' button to install the 'Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0 / 8.1 Tools', then VS attempts to launch another instance and I get a 'usage' message about some command line that apparently didn't launch correctly.

Comment: remove VS2015 completely, run setup again and now go to the custom options and select all Store Dev tools. Does this work?

Comment: Or you could just launch the Visual Studio installer again and select the missing features you need.

Comment: Yes.  Changing the installation works to get the features.  Trying to add them after the install (like in VS2013) does not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Visual Studio installation and choose Modify. Expand the Features tree along the following path.

`Windows and Web Development | Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools`

Check `Tools and Windows SDKs`.

Complete the installation.